# Gridsome how to render link icon in markdown with source-filesystem?

Tags: markdown, gridsome, gridsome-plugin, gridsome-source-filesystem

With Gridsome's [source-filesystem](https://gridsome.org/plugins/@gridsome/source-filesystem) plugin in *gridsome.config.js*:

```
plugins: [
    {
      use: '@gridsome/source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: 'docs/**/*.md',
        typeName: 'Doc',
        remark: {
          plugins: ['@gridsome/remark-prismjs'],
          autolinkHeadings: true
        }
      }
    },
```

I am able to render my markdown headings correctly:

```
## Foo Bar
```

renders as:

```
<h2 id="foo-bar">
  <a href=#foo-bar" aria-hidden="true">
    <span class="icon icon-link"></span>
  </a>
  Foo Bar
</h2>
```

but nothing in the documentation for the plugin or under [Gridsome](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues) mentions how to actually allow the link icon to be rendered or appended/how to modify `aria-hidden` to `false`.

In Gridsome how can I render markdown heading as clickable links with the span icon visible?

Comment: Got the same issue. any further information on this?

Comment: @DanielMicallef No sadly I wasnt able to find a solution from here, my queries and on their repo so I migrated to Gatsby.

Comment: I did actually, Adding `autolinkClassName` under transformers as follows: `transformers { remark: {autolinkClassName: "your new icon"}}`

Will add this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the `transformers` section in `gridsome.config.js` add `autolinkClassName` key. The value added here would be persisted as a `class` near the heading.

Example:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  transformers: {
    remark: {
      autolinkClassName: "fas fa-link mr-2",
      ...
    }
  }
}
```